# Bringing specific results to the front using one MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm setting up my geolocation feature which lists out all the countries in order of name. However, most websites have it set up where the popular countries (such as United States, United Kingdom, Canada, Australia) are at the front of the list (are shown first rather than in their assigned places). Is it possible to achieve this using the same MySQL query that I am already running to select them?

```
SELECT * FROM `global_flags` ORDER BY `country`
```

Is there a better alternative somewhere? Perhaps something that can reorganize the results after the database has already been queried? I don't want to exclude those results and then manually type them at the beginning because that would waste more space in the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) expression in your `ORDER BY` clause, and assign specific values to the countries you want to appear first.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM global_flags
  ORDER BY (CASE WHEN country="United States" THEN 0 WHEN country="United Kingdom" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), country;
```

Comment: Yep, this is just like my priority idea, except it keeps the custom order nice and separate from the data. Has anyone any idea as to which might perform better?

Comment: Well, since adding an extra column for a 256-row table seems like adding way too much data, I went with this: `SELECT * FROM global_flags ORDER BY (CASE WHEN country = 'Australia' THEN 1 WHEN country = 'Canada' THEN 1 WHEN country = 'United Kingdom' THEN 1 WHEN country = 'United States' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), country`

Comment: @Frank: I believe your solution would perform better, as the CASE has to be evaluated row-by-row at query time, as opposed to simply ordering on integers. Your solution also has the benefit of not having to copy an awkward CASE expression around if it is to be used in multiple queries.

Comment: @animuson: I haven't tested this, but you might be able to simplify the CASE expression as: `(CASE WHEN country IN ('Australia', 'Canada', 'United Kingdom', 'United States') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)`

Answer (score 2):

If the order can't be surmised from the column itself (and in your case I don't think you can), you'll need to add another column to your table (or add it in via a view) to supply the sort order.

For instance, you could have a priority column of type int. For most rows it's empty, and for those you want up front it could be 1. Say you want USA and UK as your first rows, and alphabetical for the rest:

```
SELECT * FROM global_flags ORDER BY priority DESC, country
```

will push the higher-priority items to the top of your result set. Items with the same priority class will be alphabetically sorted.

EDIT: My approach has the con that you're adding UI stuff to the data. You could always separate the priority - a UI thing - into its own table and either `INNER JOIN` it in or create a view. But perhaps [VeeArr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981159/bringing-specific-results-to-the-front-using-one-mysql-query/2981170#2981170) is the better one: it doesn't pollute your data with UI concerns.